# How do I send data via $_POST via a HTML plain-text (aka href URL)?

Tags: php, html, url

I am creating a simple webpage in which a user navigates to it, enters their username and password, and upon clicking a button (which instead I want it to be a href text URL and I cannot figure out how to do that), the PHP code kicks in and either logs them in or doesn't log them in.

I successfully was able to connect to my database using HTML/PHP, however instead of using using a submit button like so:

```
<form method="post" name="loginform" action="login_php.php">
```

I am trying to send the data from two fields using a URL like so:

```
<a href="login_php.php" class="login_button" input name="submit" type="submit">Login</a>
```

I don't really know how to do this, and I am near certain that my HTML code above for the href is just flat out wrong. Appreciate any help, thank you! :D

**edit: Styling the submit button was what I needed to do. Thanks :D**

Comment: what's the problem with using a form button? there are very good reason to sticks to the 'norm' so you need a good reason not to.

Comment: So you want your form submit button to look like a link?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? You can use a submit button and use CSS to make it look like a link...

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the plain gross button, so I have some CSS code that I'm using along with a href in HTML that makes it look like a button. My problem is that once I've done all that and have my fancy looking button, I don't know how to make it send the $_POST stuff.

Comment: style the submit button any way you like, problem solved

Comment: It's easier and much less maintenance to use an anchor as far as styling goes, to be fair. Use a regular button input too, and use js to hide it for those (very few) users without js enabled. Or `<noscript>` to hide the regular input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<a href="#" class="login_button" onclick="form.submit();" >Login</a>
```

Comment: until a user has js disabled

Comment: `<noscript><button type="submit">Log In</button></noscript>` problem solved. Although I would prefer to simply style the button like a link, it is much more work, especially for a one-off.

Answer (score 0):

why would you want to send the info via two different ways? the action="login_php.php" would kick in first and it won't let you do anything else. I'm not sure what is the purpose of using the submit button as an added source to send the info.